# React Native - Async/Await Action doesn't get fired

Tags: react-native

I have an action (among others working ones) that doesn't get fired

```
export const fetchJournalDB = () => {

  console.log('fetch dispatch');

  return async dispatch => {

    console.log('await');

    try {
      const dbResult = await db.listProduct();
      await dispatch({type: FETCH_JOURNAL, payload: dbResult});
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('await error', error);
    }
  };
};
```

If I don't use return `async dispatch` it "works", it shows the logs, otherwise I just get the first log `fetch dispatch`. Where is the problem?
Thanks

Comment: just check does adding dispatch `export const fetchJournalDB = (dispatch) => ..` make sense?

Comment: Yes, but I need it as  `async`

Comment: normally it should work but try the old function style. let me post id as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export const fetchJournalDB = () => {
return async function(dispatch){
     try{
        console.log("heyy");
        dispatch(loadinData());

     }catch{
        dispatch(fetchUsersError())

     }
 }}
```

just check it, it seems your code should work but check it without any other code in its block,

Comment: happy coding <3 @MarcoDisco